# Cloudformation Elastic Beanstalk add cloudwatch alarm when healthcheck goes red?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a CloudFormation Elastic Beanstalk application running on AWS.

I want to alert when any of the app server health turns red, but I see no option here for that: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-ec2vpc

Is there a way to create a "AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm" resource and link it to my Elastic Beanstalk application?

Answer (score 1):

Sure - create an [.ebextensions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html) folder in your application root and put a .config file in there that defines an alarm. For example,

```
Resources:
  HealthyHostCountAlarm:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
    Properties:
      ActionsEnabled: true
      AlarmActions:
      - Fn::Sub : "arn:aws:sns:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:mySns"
      AlarmDescription:
        Fn::Sub : "No more healthy hosts in ${AWSEBEnvironmentName}"
      ComparisonOperator: LessThanThreshold
      Dimensions:
      - Name: TargetGroup
        Value: 
          Fn::GetAtt : ["AWSEBV2LoadBalancerTargetGroup", "TargetGroupFullName" ]
      - Name: LoadBalancer
        Value:
          Fn::GetAtt : [ "AWSEBV2LoadBalancer", "LoadBalancerFullName" ]
      EvaluationPeriods: 1
      MetricName: HealthyHostCount
      Namespace: AWS/ApplicationELB
      OKActions:
      - Fn::Sub : "arn:aws:sns:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:mySns"
      Period: 300
      Statistic: Average
      Threshold: 1
      TreatMissingData: ignore
      Unit: Count
```

Comment: This gives me a `Contains invalid key: 'HealthyHostCountAlarm'` error.

Comment: My bad - copy/paste error from my code. The alarm needs to be in the Resources section.